# Trying to get WCF to communicate cross-domains

Tags: wcf-security

I'm trying to get two WCF services to communicate with each other in a cross-domain environment such that .NET web application calls service A on Server A in DMZ.  Service A then calls Service B via SSL on Server B which is located in a secure Domain.

I'm currently able to get Service B up and running fine.  I'm able to make calls to service B from within the Domain via SSL without any issues.  However, once I try to make the call from service A or even simply the .NET web app I run into errors.

The errors I get change depending the endpoint and binding configuration I use.  So far I've been using either wsHttpBinding or BasicHttpBinding...neither work for me.

Any suggestions or examples of what my endpoint and binding should look like?

Thanks

Dominic

Comment: going from .net web app on ServerA to wcf Service B via SSL using basicHttpBinding I get the 401 Unauthorized Error (Below are my binding and endpoint)
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Itest">
     <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
       </security>
    </binding>
<endpoint address="https://SERVERB.DOMAINNAME/DevSSLWCFTest/test.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Itest"
    contract="Testsvc.Itest" name="BasicHttpBinding_Itest" />

This is test 1...2,3,4 are to follow

Comment: Implementation #2: 
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_Itest">
     <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
       </security>
    </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
<endpoint address="same as previous"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_Itest" behaviorConfiguration ="testBehavior"
    contract="Testsvc.Itest" name="WSHttpBinding_Itest" />
<endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="testBehavior">
...
<clientCertificate
findValue="thumbprint"
x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
...

Comment: How did you use certificate? Did you bind it to a port or did you load it with wcf? If you load certificate within wcf, did you load if from file or certificate store? If it is the store, where is the certificate installed to?